# Xamarin Async and Await: UI thread is getting blocked

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, xamarin, async-await, xamarin.forms

I have this architecture in my project and sometimes UI thread is getting blocked, can someone please explain what is happening with the below code. Thanks

I am making a service call asyncronously from xamarin.forms viewmodel

Following is the flow

View--->ViewModel---ClassA--->ClassB--Make a service call from here

Code

Scenario 1

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    private HomeVM model;

    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        model = new HomeVM();
        model.MainText = ReturnBool().Result;
        this.BindingContext = model;
    }
    public async Task<string> ReturnBool()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        var r = await new WS().ReturnBool();
        IsBusy = false;---------------------------------------Not hitting the breakpoint here
        return r;
    }
}

public interface IWS
{
    Task<string> ReturnBool();
}

public class WS : IWS
{
    public Task<string> ReturnBool()
    {
        return ServiceOperations.ReturnBool();
    }
}

internal class ServiceOperations
{
    public async static Task<string> ReturnBool()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://testmyapi.azurewebsites.net/", string.Empty)); 
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = uri;
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response = await client.GetAsync("/api/Values/Get");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                string str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(content);
                return str;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Scenario 2

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
{
    private HomeVM model;

    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        model = new HomeVM(); 
        this.BindingContext = model;
    } 
}

public class HomeVM : BaseVM
{
    private string mainText;

    public string MainText
    {
        get { return mainText; }
        set
        {
            mainText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MainText");
        }
    }

    public HomeVM()
    {
        MainText = ReturnBool().Result; 
    }

    public async Task<string> ReturnBool()
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        var r = await new WS().ReturnBool();
        IsBusy = false;---------------------------------------Not hitting the breakpoint here
        return r;
    }
}


public interface IWS
{
    Task<string> ReturnBool();
}

public class WS : IWS
{
    public Task<string> ReturnBool()
    {
        return ServiceOperations.ReturnBool();
    }
}

internal class ServiceOperations
{
    public async static Task<string> ReturnBool()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://testmyapi.azurewebsites.net/", string.Empty)); 
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = uri;
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            response = await client.GetAsync("/api/Values/Get");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                string str = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(content);
                return str;
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ReturnBool` is not awaiting for the call, not sure if it just sends the Task through or hangs waiting for it. Then again, if it never gets to a breakpoint there, there is no reply but it shouldn't hang the thread.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I think it hangs waiting for it but it is never returning anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ReturnBool().Result in the constructor. The return call will block your UI thread. Move that code to the controller action methods without using ".Result" part. Ensure that the methods are async and always return a Task.